# Sql driver message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm having a problem where I can't connect to a Microsoft SQL server from c++.
This is my functions to connect. But it says that can't connect to db.

**code**:

```cpp
void sql1() {
    SQLHANDLE SQLEnvHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLConnectionHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLStatementHandle = NULL;
    SQLRETURN retCode = 0;
    char SQLQuery[] = "SELECT * FROM annotationscfg";

    do {
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &SQLEnvHandle))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(SQLEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLEnvHandle, &SQLConnectionHandle))
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetConnectAttr(SQLConnectionHandle, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0))
            break;
        SQLCHAR retConString[1024];
        switch (SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL SERVER}; SERVER=localhost\SQLEXPRESS, 1433; DATABASE=teste2; UID=root; PWD=1234567890", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)) {
        case SQL_SUCCESS:
            break;
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            break;
        case SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND:
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        case SQL_ERROR:
            showSqlError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (retCode == -1)
            break;
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLConnectionHandle, &SQLStatementHandle))
            break;
```

This is my SQL table:
[image: My sql Table]

And this is my error on console:
[image: Error on console]

Can you find any error in this?

Comment: You cannot supply a port number when you use an instance name. Use one or the other - not both. Express is a named instance and it will generally use a dynamic port. 1433 is the port generally used for a default instance. Start by removing the port number and verify that your server instance is running and that you can connect to it using SSMS.

Comment: I tried that but it has the same result